# Finding unknown angles of a rhombus given side length and area

Tags: trigonometry, angle, quadrilateral

> Given that the area of a rhombus is $40 \text{cm}^2$ and that each side has a length of $15 \text{cm}$, find the angles of the rhombus.

It's from a 8th-grade school math textbook.

Comment: The area of a parallelogram with side lengths $a$ and $b$ is $ab\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the area of a triangle is given by $\frac{sin(A)bc}{2}$, and there are two isosceles triangles which make up the rhombus (imagine drawing a diagonal, splitting the rhombus in two) we know that $sin(A)bc=area$. (by applying the sine rule to each of the smaller triangles).

[image: stuff]

Substituting area = 40, b=c=15 yields $sin(A)=\frac{8}{45}$ so $A=10.24$ or $169.76$ degrees.

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed answer? You see, I'm only in the 8th grade, so even the most obvious things might not be as obvious to me.

Comment: I don't understand how drawing diagonals can give any info. We DON'T know it; it's not given. We can't find it---we don't know the height so that we can use the pythagorean theorem to do the rest. To find the height, we also need the angle to put trigonometric ratios to use. But we don't even know that---that's after all what we have to find at the end.

Comment: Could you include a diagram? Things would be much more clearer to me then.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

[image]

$h\cdot 15=40\implies h=\dfrac{40}{15}$

Now you know the height of Rhombus. Carry it from here...

Comment: A nice approach.